# Compile Error: Expected Function or Variable in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a function that is supposed to take a time, ex, 05:00:00 and check it with the current time (and an optional another time), and if the time in the argument has already passed, it's supposed to return the same time, but the next day.

For example, if `tm = 05:00:00` and now = `2018-08-14 12:00:00`, then the function should return `2018-08-15 05:00:00`, but if the time hasn't passed, ex. `tm = 19:00` i.e., now < tm, then it should return `2018-08-14 19:00`.

My function is (in a separate module):

```
'Day Adjustment
Sub DayAdjust(tm As Double, Optional tm2 As Double = 0)
    If tm2 = 0 Then
        tm2 = DayAdjust(tm)
    End If

    If (Date + tm) < Now() Or (Date + tm) < tm2 Then
        tm = (Date + 1 + tm)
    End If
    MsgBox tm
    DayAdjust = tm
End Sub
```

The code that calls the function is:

```
Dim schStart, schEnd As Double
schStart = Range("cdh_schStart").Value
schStartTime = DayAdjust(CDbl(schStart))
schEnd = Range("cdh_schEnd").Value
schEndTime = DayAdjust(schEnd, schStart)
```

The cell `cdh_schStart` contains the value `05:00:00`, and `cdh_schEnd` has `08:00:00` with the present system time set to `2018-08-14 18:30:00`.

On the 3rd line, `schStartTime = DayAdjust(CDbl(schStart))`, I get the error:

> Compile Error:
>
> Expected Function or Variable

I need some help figuring out why this happens and how to fix it.

Comment: It's because you defined `DayAdjust` as a Sub not a Function.

Comment: I think you are likely to end up with an infinite loop due to that first section of code if you don't pass `tm2` or pass 0 by mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting an assignment with   `schStartTime = DayAdjust(CDbl(schStart))` so your sub needs to be written as a function. Indeed, you have a return value assignment in your sub but I guess you typo'd or didn't realise it must be declared as a function .

Good point raised by @Rory re potential for infinite loop with tm2 if passed as zero or is not supplied, and defaults to zero, as the function will be called recursively without a breakout. You will need to find an appropriate way to handle this.

```
Public Function DayAdjust(tm As Double, Optional tm2 As Double = 0) As Variant
    If tm2 = 0 Then
        tm2 = DayAdjust(tm)
    End If

    If (Date + tm) < Now() Or (Date + tm) < tm2 Then
        tm = (Date + 1 + tm)
    End If
    MsgBox tm
    DayAdjust = tm
End Function
```